# How do I remove a single-symbol junk "file" in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, rm

The file appeared after untar'ing a tar.gz file. I've seen this before and an old colleague made a recommendation which worked, but have since lost that command.

The file is literally:

```
-
```

It is 1541 bytes with root permissions.

I tried a slew of "sudo rm" commands. Any thinking-outside-the-box suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the command

```
 sudo rm -- -
```

The -- turns off switches.